# 404 resource not found error in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am facing a problem  in deploying my Application on server...
it Shows error 404 resource not found ,it works fin onlocal development server

*Html*

```
<select class="select-box1" id="ddlStates" name="State">
<option value="0">--Select State --</option>
<option value="35">Alabama</option>
<option value="36">Alaska</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="btnDevicesSearch" class="reset-btn">SEARCH</button>
```

*Script*

```
 $('#btnDevicesSearch').click(function () {
            //debugger

            //var formresult = $('#frmDeviceSearch').validationEngine('validate');
            //if (!formresult) {
            //    return false;
            //}
            //else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@(Url.Action("Search", "Devices"))',
                    async: false,
                    type: 'Post',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ SerialNo: $('#txtSearchSerialNo').val(), ItemName: $('#txtSearchItemName').val(), ItemType: $('#txtSearchItemType').val(), DeviceId: $('#txtSearchDeviceId').val(), To: $('#dtSearchTo').val(), From: $('#dtSearchFrom').val() }),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (list) {
                        if (list !== null) {
                        alert(list.value)
                        }
                    },
                });
                window.location = "/Devices/DeviceList";
            //}
        });
```

Comment: Check your generated HTML code to see if the URL was correctly rendered. Maybe a routing issue.

Comment: Which URL causes that? There appears to be two here, my guess would be `/Devices/DeviceList`, you probably want `@Url.Action("Devices", "DeviceList")`.

Comment: @rkawano,@James Thanks guys u saved my day,App root was added & is working fine like /MyApplication/Devices/DeviceList...